# Зaпретить поворот активити - как?

Tags: java, android

Как зaпретить повоpот aктивити?

Comment: Какие результаты принесли собственные поиски?

Comment: Никаких, к сожалению

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2730894/4711135

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Вы можете мне объяснить как так получается, что описании тревог написано, что чтобы закрыть вопрос нужно 6 тревог, а на этом всего 5, и он закрыт как дубликат. (я не обижаюсь, что мой вопрос закрыт, поскольку он действительно дубликат)

Comment: @arkad не знаю, дубликат и все ))

Answer (score 0):

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Если тестить на эмуляторе то не сработает, попробуй на реальном телефоне.